# How do features limiting using OnGuard

Tags: delphi, onguard

I'm a newbie at on guard and I'm trying to limit some features using TPONGuard.

Comment: I'm trying Enable/Disable some of my software features based on TPOnGuard release code evaluete.

Comment: Yes, you said that already. But what is your *question*? What part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the demo Examples directory try looking at frm_readme.pas in the RegDemo, it could give you some help.

But basically the registrationcodes, can be used to "securely" lock a number (32 bit) to a computer.
How you use those bits is up to you.
You could user lower 16 bits as serialnumber and upper 16 bits as modules.
Or you can send 2 registrations codes.
One with bit 31 =0 that you use for serial number and on with bit 31=1 an have bits 0-30 for signaling 30 different features enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

OnGuard comes with a full manual of 125 pages. Look at and read the PDF file "manual.pdf".

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think the almost questions asked here has answer in a manual, and if I asked here may be because I don't find it in a cleary way in the manual.

Comment: You asked something that **is** explained in the manual. If you had a specific question I would have had a specific answer. If you had reached page 103 of the manual, you would have find something...